# Asymptotic sums and big-O notation

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Suppose I have to compute the following asymptotic sum ($x\rightarrow\infty$):
$$
S(x):=\sum_{n\leq f(x)} O(g(x,n))\;,
$$
where the function $g(x,n)$ is non-decreasing in $n$, so that in our case $g(x,n)\leq g(x,f(x))=:G(x)$.
Now my problem is: can I say that
$$
S(x)=O(f(x)G(x))
$$
as $x\rightarrow\infty$?

For example, I have this problem: an unconditional version of Chebotarev Density Theorem (Lagarias, Odlyzko) says that if $n\leq (\log x)^{1/7}$ then
$$
\pi(x,n) = \frac1{k_n}{\rm li}(x) + O(x \exp(-A\sqrt{\log x}/n))\;,
$$
for a certain absolute constant $A$. I'm interested in what happens when I perform the sum
$$
\sum_{n\leq (\log x)^{1/7}} g(n) \pi(x,n)
$$
where $g(n)$ is an arithmetic function. In particular, how should I deal the error term
$$
\sum_{n\leq (\log x)^{1/7}} g(n)O(x \exp(-A\sqrt{\log x}/n))\;?
$$
I wrote it as 
$$
\sum_{n\leq (\log x)^{1/7}} g(n)O(x \exp(-A(\log x)^{4/15}))
$$
but then I'd like to deal with something like
$$
O\left( \sum_{n\leq (\log x)^{1/7}} g(n)x \exp(-A(\log x)^{4/15})\right)\;,
$$ 
but I'm afrai I can't do it. Am I wrong?

I hope the question is clear, maybe it's trivial but I don't know a certain answer.

Comment: The $O(\cdot)$ in your first sum -- what is it taken with regard with?

Comment: It's an $O$ concerning the variable $x$, hence I suppose I can surely say that $S(x) = \sum_{n\leq g(x)} O(G(x))$, the problem is the following equality which I suppose it's not true...

Comment: A question that is left here (I believe) is how that asymptotic $O(\cdot)$ of each summand $s(x,n)$ is then taken with regard to the second argument. Namely, is the "constant" instead the $O(\cdot)$ depending on $n$? Is it $\forall n,\exists A_n,c_n$ such that $s(x,n) \leq  c_n g(x,n)$ for all $x\geq A_n$, or $\exists A,c$ such that $\forall n$,$s(x,n) \leq  c g(x,n)$ for all $x\geq A$ ? In that case, forgetting the $O(\cdot)$ for a moment: you have $\sum_{n=1}^{f(x)} g(x,n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{f(x)} g(x,f(x)) = f(x) g(x,f(x))$, which should be enough indeed to get what  you need.

Comment: OK I understand what you mean, it's the first case. But in general I'm interested in the second question, so you can also forget about the dependance on $n$.

Comment: If the asymptotics do not depend on the second parameter, but only on the first (second case in my comment), then you should be good. Is that what you mean you're interested in?

Comment: I removed the second part of my question, which I realized this morning (yesterday I was very tired) was non-sense. The question I posed is a generalization of a problem I'm dealing with, I'm adding it to the main question. Thanks for your attention Clement!